# Vassal levies raised too long, but where?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I have the warning *"Vassal levies raised too long"* at the top of the screen, but I don't have any troops anywhere, and no option to dismiss levies on either the Military window or any of my County windows.

Can I find these troops and disband them, or is this a bug?

Comment: Ships count too. Check for those. And the opinion malus from that lasts ticks down every X(?) days, just as it ticks up every X days, so it can stick around even if you've already disbanded everything.

Comment: I think @Affine hit the nail. If you raised all of the vassals levies to fight some distant war, and then disbanded them, he'll still hate you for it. After some time, all is forgotten, though.

Comment: @Affine that makes sense, as it did go away eventually. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The opinion penalty for raised levies ticks down by 1 point every X days (currently 61, may be different across patches) after dismissing troops, just as they tick up every X for having raised troops. Thus the penalty and notification will remain for some time even after dismissing your vassal's troops.

Additionally, though this may not be the case here, ships count as raised levies as well. I've forgotten about some fleets off in some corner of the map before, leading to some hilariously high penalties.

Comment: Ships!!! Damn it!